# Is there a way for me to remove the Year,Month,Day from an interval?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want this 0-0 0 502:9:14 to be this 502:9:14.

```
SELECT
    ride_id,
    started_at, --timestamp
    ended_at, -- timestamp
    ended_at - started_at AS ride_length, --interval
FROM `project-id.bike_share.202102`
ORDER BY ride_length DESC
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want this 0-0 0 502:9:14 to be this 502:9:14

Try below simple approach

```
SELECT
  ride_id,
  started_at, 
  ended_at, 
  ended_at - started_at AS ride_length, 
  replace('' || (ended_at - started_at), '0-0 0 ', '') AS ride_length_as_hhmmss, 
FROM `project-id.bike_share.202102`
```

below is example of output

[image]

Comment: Will it return as string or interval the data type? If it string, am i able to perform aggregate function such as mean,max,min on it?

Comment: it obviously returns string because requested format (as it is asked for in current question) can ONLY be achieved via string! if you need to do aggregations  - post new question with all related details along with sample of input data and expected result and we will be happy to help you further

Answer (score 2):

you might wanna consider normalizing the interval by using `justify_interval`:

```
SELECT
    ride_id,
    started_at, --timestamp
    ended_at, -- timestamp
    justify_interval(ended_at - started_at) AS ride_length --interval
FROM `project-id.bike_share.202102`
ORDER BY ride_length DESC
```

output sample:

```
Row     justified_ride_length    ride_length    
1       0-0 20 22:19:14          0-0 0 502:19:14
```

---

otherwise, I think you have to use extract :

```
select concat(extract(hour from i),':',extract(minute from i),':',extract(second from i)) ride_length_2
FROM `project-id.bike_share.202102` t
left join unnest ([t.ended_at - t.started_at]) as i
```

output sample :

```
Row     ride_length        ride_length_2    
1       0-0 0 502:19:14    502:19:14
```

Comment: I actually need the answer in HH:MM:SS format. Thanks

Comment: @Jay then see updated answer.

Comment: Using the concat function, will it return as interval or string the data type?

Comment: @Jay it would be string